# Zend Framework Give 404 Error From Modal

Tags: php, zend-framework

i have work On https://www.taskguru.co.ke/job/findproscat using Zendframework , now its show only one user job post, but i like to view page multiple job post at one page, but when i try to add foreach loop its return 404 error.. see the below code and help me out of this problem...!

Controller :

```
class JobController extends Zend_Controller_Action
{

public function findproscatAction(){ 
  global $objSession ;  
  $this->view->pageHeading="Hire Task Guru"; 
  $this->_helper->layout()->setLayout('profilepage'); 
  $sort_by =$this->_getParam('sort_by');
  $this->view->sort_by=$sort_by;
  $jobdata = $this->generalMethod->getAllRecordFromLeftJoin('jobpost',"users","jobpost.job_postby=users.user_id","1","","");
  $this->view->jobdata=$jobdata;


  if(!$sort_by)
  {
   $sort_by=0;
  } 

     $data = $this->modelJob->getFulltimeJoblistpro($jobdata[0],$sort_by);

  $this->view->data=$data;    
  $this->view->setting = $this->getInviteapro();
 }
}
```

Modal:

```
public function getFulltimeJob($data,$sortby)
     {


   $this->_name = 'users';
   if($sortby=='1')
   {
    $sortval='distance';
   }
   else if($sortby=='2')
   {
    $sortval="concat(u.user_first_name,' ',u.user_last_name) ASC";
   }
   else if($sortby=='3')
   {
    $sortval='q.qualification_passingyear';
   }
   else if($sortby=='4')
   {
    $sortval='w.workexperience_position';
   }
   else
   {
     $sortval='dt.sub_title';
   }
   $whr="";
   if($data['job_degree_more']!='')
  {
   $whr=" or q.qualification_oneline IN (".$data['job_degree_more'].")";
  }
   $result = $this->getAdapter()->select()->from(array('u' => 'users'),array('distance'=>"(((acos(sin((".$data['user_latitude']."*pi()/180)) * 
            sin((`user_latitude`*pi()/180))+cos((".$data['user_latitude']."*pi()/180)) * 
            cos((`user_latitude`*pi()/180))  cos(((".$data['user_longitude']."- `user_longitude`) 
            pi()/180))))*180/pi())*60)","u.user_first_name","u.user_last_name","u.vanity_username","u.user_image","u.user_id","u.company_name"))
        ->joinLeft(array('q' => 'qualification'), 'u.user_id = q.qualification_uid')
        ->joinLeft(array('dt' => 'subdegreetitle'), 'q.qualification_oneline = dt.subtitle_id')
        ->joinLeft(array('d' => 'degree_title'), 'dt.title_id = d.title_id')
        ->joinLeft(array('vq' => 'verified_qualification'),  'q.qualification_id= vq.qualification_id',array("(CASE when user_iscompany = '0' then count(vq.qualification_id) else 4 end) as totalVQ"))
        ->joinLeft(array('w' => 'workexperience'),  'u.user_id= w.workexperience_uid')
        ->where("(q.qualification_oneline = '".$data['job_degree']."' ".$whr.") and user_type='1' and go_full_time='1' and q.qualification_status='1'")  
        //->where("user_type='1' and go_full_time='1' and q.qualification_status='1'")
        ->having("totalVQ >= 4");

  $result=$result->order($sortval);
  $result = $result->query()->fetchAll(); 
  return $result;
  }
```

i want to run foreach like

```
foreach($jobdata as $key =>$val){
  $data = $this->modelJob->getFulltimeJoblistpro($jobdata[$key],$sort_by);
}
```

but unfortunately its give 404 error..

plz help me...!

Comment: Which url gives you `404`?? Show your view code.

Comment: https://www.taskguru.co.ke/job/findproscat

Comment: this is controller above

Comment: I have checked your url and it's not getting `404`.